# If I have two columns, how can I select all distinct values of columnA where columnB is never a specific value given that columnA is the same value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So let's say I have two columns:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 |
| 1 | 299 |
| 2 | 300 |
| 2 | 300 |
| 3 | 299 |
| 3 | 299 |

I want to look for distinct values of A such that there is never a combination of A and B where B equals 300.
In my example, I would want to return the columnA value 3.

Result

| A |
| --- |
| 3 |

How do I accomplish this with SQL?

Comment: Please add your expected result.

Comment: @Rezu My expected result would just be the value 3 for this scenario, since it is the only id from columnA that doesn't contain a corresponding value of 300 in columnB.

Comment: Don't worry too much about the downvotes by the way. I think you have explained your problem properly. It is just that you are supposed to try something yourself and tell us where exactly you got stuck. With this kind of task, however, it is often difficult for SQL beginners to come up with anything.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called conditional aggregation. You want to aggregate by A (i.e. show A values in your result) and have a check only applied on particular B values. For instance:

```
select a
from mytable
group by a
having count(case when b = 300 then 1 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `subquery` will give the results.

Exclude the Rows using the `NOT IN` keyword

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE ColumnA NOT IN(
    SELECT ColumnA FROM Table WHERE ColumnB=300)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT DISTINCT A 
FROM tbl t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM Tbl t2 WHERE t2.A=t1.B AND t2.B=300)
```